# Moving Attachments To Folder And Attaching Them With Email

Tags: php, upload, attachment, email-attachments

I have a simple page, which is sending an Email message and multiple attachments, through phpmailer.
I have to attach the multiple attachments to the Email message to send, and also upload these files o server at same time, For which i m using the following loop:

```
 $MyUploads = array();

 foreach(array_keys($_FILES['attach']['name']) as $key)
 { $Location="uploads/";

 $name=$_FILES['attach']['name'][$key];
 $filePath = $Location . $name;
 $source = $_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'][$key]; // location of PHP's temporary file for 
 $tmp=$_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'][$key];

 if($mail->AddAttachment($source, $name))
  {if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $filePath)){
 $MyUploads[] = $filePath;}
 else
 {$MyUploads[]='';
 echo "not uploaded";}
 }
 }
```

The problem is, when i use the function move_uploaded_file(), the files are uploaded to the server folder, but are not sent with the attachments. As i comment out this function the attachments are sended.

Can;t find out, why these two dnt work together. Please any body help

Comment: Related: [retrieving images from database and displaying all on a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196929/retrieving-images-from-database-and-displaying-all-on-a-page)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the loop that sends Attachments, And move them to a target path, for further use. I hope any one else can be helped by this:

```
$MyUploads = array();
$numFiles = count(array_filter($_FILES['attach']['name']));

for ($i = 0; $i < $numFiles; ++$i) {
    $target_path = 'uploads/' . basename($_FILES['attach']['name'][$i]);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
        echo "the file ".basename($_FILES['attach']['name'][$i])." has been uploaded<br />";
        $MyUploads[] = $target_path;
        echo $MyUploads;
        $mail->AddAttachment($target_path);
    }
}
```