# retrieving images from database and displaying all on a page

Tags: php, image, upload, phpmyadmin

I have 5 attachments whose paths are stored in database (5) columns. I am retrieving the paths as follows for the first file.

```
$path1=$rowArray['file1'];
$path2=$rowArray['file2'];
<?php printf('<a href="%s" >View all Files</a>',$path1); ?>
```

where `$path1` is the path of the first file, and by clicking on View all Files, the image is shown on the next page.

I want to show all the 5 images on the same page under View all Files links.

How can i do it. Hope u all understand. I have applied a loop to show, them all, but it doesnot help. Please provide me a valid solution for this.

Comment: Is there a common unique id shared between all the image records?

Comment: `record_id|image1|image2|image3|image4|image5`

Comment: @Dale Yes all the image share one id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No doubt you cannot do it the way you want, with one link, show all your images. I guess the best way to do it is to send the file names or ids on your URL and check for it on your target PHP, this way you can show them.

Comment: hmmm, got it. Please if u find any code help, on how to show them on target page, bcz i have thought of this way but cant figure it out..

Comment: You would create a link to (for example) `show_images.php?record_id=$record_id` where $record_id is the id of the record from your database, in show_images.php you would select the image columns and if the are not empty, create an <img> tag for each column.

Comment: @Dale I have used the folllowing img tag to show image, but only a cracked img icon is shown `code`print "<img src='<?php $path1 ?>' />"; `code`. Please cud u help

Comment: I can suggest a few topics that I think are relevant here, http://uk.php.net/mysql_query, http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: @HanyaIdrees the problem with your code is the missing `echo`, it should be: `<img src='<?php echo $path1 ?>' />`

Answer (score 1):

you need javascript for that, an hover on the links would create a div with the image/s which src attribute would be the link's path..